# Disabling the Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver using Group Policy

Tags: group-policy, windows-8, windows-8.1

I need to campus-wide disable the Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver using Group Policy / SCCM / or any other means of centralized management, because I've written my own LLDP broadcast service I plan on using instead of the crippled MS implementation.

I tried googling but wasn't able to come up with a working solution.

[image: Ethernet Properties Window]

**EDIT:**
I took two registry snapshots and compared them, the three keys that change when the checkbox is toggled are located under

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MsLldp\Linkage
```

The keys are Bind / Route / Export

The problem is when these keys are deleted / emptied, the checkbox turns itself back on.

Comment: I'm curious to know what's so bad about the MS LLDP service? Some time ago I wanted LLDP for Windows 7 and found this:
http://www.hanewin.net/lldp-e.htm
it's not really shareware, it runs for a number of days before the evaluation expires.

Comment: there's nothing bad as such. the problem is that you can't configure what information the LLDP Data Units (LLDPDUs) should contain. I found that we need more than what Microsoft provides out of the box (such as the current IP, or probably the user who's currently logged on), so I wrote my own implementation of the LLDP protocol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright.

I just deleted the entire

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MsLldp\
```

key and while that turned the check box on again, Windows actually stops sending LLDP PDUs (confirmed that using Wireshark)

Comment: Since you already know what registry values to change, and because this question was related to doing this via GPO: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2007/08/14/deploying-custom-registry-changes-through-group-policy.aspx - This should allow you to deploy via GPO.